# Unity-iPhone" requires a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, xcode5

please help me :(!!!!
I'm new to unity and Xcode too, I just Build my unity project to the Xcode but I faced this problem and today is the third day that I couldn't solve it.

please please help me and provide a detailed answer

[image: how to add provisioning profile]
[image: this is the error that appears]

Comment: Have you signed up for an Apple developer membership (free is ok to start) and added your Apple ID login details to Xcode?

Comment: can you please provide details for your response?

Comment: @Nada I suggest you watch some tutorial on how to build for iphone. else i feel its not gonna be easy coz when i started building for ios it was pretty confusing :)

Comment: You need to go to https://developer.Apple.com and sign up. You can then sign in to your Apple account in Xcode preferences. This will allow you to select a team and create a provisioning profile in the signing and capabilities tab.